# Calculating Shortest Path using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shortest-path

I am working on QGIS - 1.8 Version and frequently getting an error while using Road Graph and Shortest Path Options.

Can you suggest or provide a solution?

Answer (score 2):

[This is the official tutorial](http://gis-lab.info/qa/road-graph-eng.html) that can be used as an introduction to this plugin.

If it doesn't work as expected report this behaviour as bug to the developer ( look at the bottom of that page ).